# How can this script apply a class to all specified HTML elements, regardless of how many elements there are?

Tags: jquery

In the following example, this script applies the class 'green' to all 'span' HTML elements randomly, and at a steady rate.

```
var items = $('span').get();
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
    $(items[random_number]).addClass('green');
    items.splice(random_number, 1);
    if (items.length === 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
     }, 10);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DUbQB/

I've updated it so that it changes 2 elements per interval, simply by calling the function twice.

```
var items = $('span').get();
var interval = setInterval(function() {

    function rand(random_number) {
    var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
    $(items[random_number]).addClass('green');
    items.splice(random_number, 1);
    }

    rand(1);
    rand(2);

    if (items.length === 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DUbQB/3/

All I want to know is, is there a way to get this script to randomly turn all elements green in the **same time**, regardless of how many elements there are?

For example, http://jsfiddle.net/DUbQB/3/ completes in ten intervals because there's twenty elements and the random function is called twice.

But if there were forty elements, the script would take twenty intervals, and so twice as long. How could this script always take the same amount of time to complete, regardless of how many elements there are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a JS developer but this caught me to try out (the first time I tried JSFiddle and it's really cool).

Here's a solution that results in a constant number of steps even if there are rounding differences.

```
function DoTransition() {
    var items = $('span').get();
    var steps = 10;
    var residuum = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {

        function rand() {
            var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
            $(items[random_number]).addClass('green');
            items.splice(random_number, 1);
        }

        var localSteps = items.length / steps + residuum;
        residuum = localSteps - Math.round(localSteps);
        localSteps = Math.round(localSteps);
        for (var i = 0; i < localSteps; i++) {
            rand();
        }

        steps--;

        if (items.length === 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 500);
}

DoTransition();
```

UPDATE: fixed the problem with a small number of items... just a call to Math.round was missing. Now there are intermediate steps with 0 items updated if required. For testing I've created a new version that updates the asterisk with the localSteps variable (http://jsfiddle.net/vQDhf/).

UPDATE2: now a mathematically correct transition that distributes equally over the time line.

Comment: +1 Actually...it seems to work: for the first couple intervals it does extra elements to normalize the ratio, keeping a constant num of steps. The only issue seems to be when there are less elements than steps. I don't know if there's any case when the ratio wouldn't self-correct quickly enough, though I think it's possible. http://jsfiddle.net/fjqe3/

Comment: the localSteps are always calculated as the number of *remaining* items divided by the number of *remaining* steps. So in the end you have nearly constant number of items for each step (the max difference is 1 because of the rounding thing). And if the number of items is less than the number of steps, you get a step somewhere in between where no item is modified. So no problem with this either.

Comment: Nah, I tested with 5 items. It just does 5 steps and stops.

Comment: @nbrooks Yep, I also tried in the meantime and you are right that it does not do what I would expect with a small number of items. No clue why. But the other points I've stated are true.

Comment: It's a nice approach and the jsfiddle is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to do small math calculation to determine either how fast to run the interval or how many elements to change per interval.

For example, if you want it to complete in 5000ms, then you just do:

```
var items = $('span').get();
var intervalTime = 5000 / items.length;
```

Then use that `intervalTime` with the `setInterval()` call.  This will complete the operation in 5000ms no matter how many spans there are.

Comment: This *is* technically right, though OP did say *always take the same amount of intervals to complete*, I'm sure they really just meant the same amount of time. You should add though that if OP takes this approach they should remove the second call to `rand` in the interval—or it will go twice as fast.

Answer (score 1):

*"At the same rate"* means the same number of operations per number of intervals. In other words, what you're currently doing (2 elem/interval) is a constant rate. What you are instead asking for is *in the same number of intervals*. That is also doable, but note that it requires a predefined number of intervals, and will change the rate depending on the number of elements.

```
var numIntervals = SOME_PREDEFINED_VALUE; // e.g. always use 4 intervals
var items = $('span').get();

var elemsPerInterval = Math.floor(items.length/numIntervals);
var extraElems = elemsPerInterval * numIntervals;

var interval = setInterval(function() {

    function rand() {
        var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
        $(items[random_number]).addClass('green');
        items.splice(random_number, 1);
    }

    // do one extra element per iteration to account
    // for residuals due to rounding
    int j = extraElems-- > 0 ? -1 : 0;

    while ( j < elemsPerInterval ) {
        rand();
        j++;
    }

    if (items.length === 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: P.S. Note that there is no reason to pass a parameter to `rand`, because you never used it: thus I removed it.

Comment: Small thing to note that's not perfect: if you have e.g. 21 elements it will take 11 steps to complete instead of 10 because of a rounding difference. See alternative Solution.

Comment: @CSharper Thanks, fixed the rounding error (although it would actually have ended up finishing faster, because it would have to do an extra element each iteration for `j` to pass the floating point val `elemsPerInterval`)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/CA97a/

Thanks @JWH give it a timer http://jsfiddle.net/CA97a/5/

I think change the timer interval will be more simple

```
<div class="container">
</div>

<script>
// Use for test
for (var i=0; i < 20 /*Count*/; i++) {
    $(".container").append("<span> "+i+" </span>");
}

// Script start
var items = $('span').get();
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
    $(items[random_number]).addClass('green');
    items.splice(random_number, 1);

    if (items.length <= 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 5000/items.length); // Finish in 5 sec
</script>
```

I have a another idea, this way time will be more accurate, I have test it with 10K  in Firefox, don't feel too much lag
http://jsfiddle.net/LmE6J/

```
$("span").each(function () {
    function closure(s) {
        return function () {
            $(s).addClass("green");
        };
    }
    setTimeout(closure(this), (Math.random()*Math.floor(5000)));
});
```

Comment: But with that you get in trouble if you have thousands of items. The transition takes much longer if you do many of those small updates instead of a few big changes.

Comment: This is for less than 1K solution =P

Comment: Yeah, pretty good but just not versatile enough. 

Compare 

http://jsfiddle.net/CA97a/5/
with

http://jsfiddle.net/CA97a/4/

Not having a go, just pointing it out :P

Comment: So I think the second one is better and more accurate, do you have idea to count the time of second one =)